# Isomorphism $T_e(\mathbb{R^*}) \leftrightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: differential-geometry

I know that there is an isomorphism $T_e(\mathbb{R}) \leftrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$X \in T_e(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto (X(x\mapsto x))$

$v \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto X_v : f \mapsto \frac{d}{dh}|_{h=0} f(e+hv)$

But what about an isomorphism

$T_e(\mathbb{R^*}) \leftrightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: What is $\mathbb R^*$? The dual space?

Comment: it is just $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$

Comment: For any open subset $U \subseteq M$ and $p \in U$, $T_p U \cong T_pM$.